# Is there any API which can provide information on different animal species?

Tags: api, data

I am working on a project (not a programming project) where we require a lot of information about different species such as average weight, lifespan, height, population numbers, endangered status etc.

I have been looking for an API to provide this information so that I don't have to manually search for it for over 100 species and I can't find anything that provides the information.

The best I have found so far is an API provided by the [IUCN Red list](https://apiv3.iucnredlist.org/api/v3/docs), but this doesn't have all the information required (e.g. no lifespan data or weight)

Are there any APIs available which will provide this information?

Comment: Not sure what kind of API you're after (for what progamming language etc) – but if you're looking for data, your question might better fit at our sister site [Open Data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (please check behind that link before posting there to make sure your question is accepted on the site).

Comment: I was looking for a web API, which would return JSON data. Thanks for the link. I didn't know about that site. I'll look into posting there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikidata](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Main_Page) offers a powerful query interface for their knowledge graph.

For your specific question, there might be a predefined example that might get you started. This a predefined query which will create a list with the latin names of many species, linked to a page with data from the infoboxes and other data  on Wikipedia.

Go to https://query.wikidata.org/

Klick On Examples. The button is at the top of the page.

In the pull-down menu, click on "Items with a Wikispecies sitelink" (it's #9 on the list)

Click on the Run Icon. (Its the  `|>` icon on the Blue Background)

Of course you can adapt the query to your needs. Perhaps ask on Stackoverflow.com if you need help with the SPARQL query language or the Wikidata ontology.

For example, for Cheetahs there are quite a few [attributes](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q23907) available such as birth weight, lifespan, ...

By the way, Google has an even larger knowledge graph with a  [search API](https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph) that works similar to Wikidata's.